# Distribute boolean values uniformly over array (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting, distribution

I have a boolean array with a fixed length. Values are defaulted to `false`.
I need to fill the array with N values of `true`, that are mostly evenly distributed and spreaded over the array.

For example: If length is 7 and N is 3, it would look something like this:
`[false, true, false, true, false, true, false]`

If length is 14 and N is 5, it would look something like this:
`[false, false, true, false, false, true, false, false, true, false, true, false, true, false]`

The thing is, there isn't a strict rule of how to spread it, only that it should be spreaded **mostly** in an even matter (perhaps with a rule that the first and last elements won't be true, but not necessary).

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/ykvg0bna/

Comment: @Berto99 Javasript, but I need the idea mostly

Comment: @ChrisG Yes! Could you explain what you did there?

Comment: I start with an array like `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`, then multiply each number by a suitable factor to spread the numbers over [0 - 11] and round it so I get integers. Then I use the resulting indices to set these array elements to true.

Comment: So what have you tried so far? I would simply set every `i*length/N th` index to true.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function createBoolArray(len, trues) {
  const arr = new Array(len).fill(false);
  
  let leftTrues = trues;
  let left = len;
  let divisor = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < len && leftTrues > 0;) {
    left = len - i;
    divisor = Math.floor(left / leftTrues);
    
    if(Math.floor(left / divisor) > leftTrues) {
      i = i + divisor + 1;
      arr[i - 1] = true;
    } else {
      i = i + divisor;
      arr[i - 1] = true;
    }
    leftTrues--;
  }
  
  return arr;
}

console.log(createBoolArray(14, 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing this (similar to what @ChrisG suggested):

```
function createBoolArray(len, trues) {
  const arr = new Array(len).fill(false);
  new Array(trues).fill(0).map((_, i) => 
  Math.floor((i+1) * (len-1) / trues))
 .forEach(e => arr[e] = true);

  return arr;
}

console.log(createBoolArray(14, 5))
```